# IBM437 charset issue on IE10

Tags: css, character-encoding, internet-explorer-10

I have two css files being loaded in a page. Both have charset defiend as IBM437.

While rendering the page on IE10 one css file gets recognized but the other one is not.

I removed the charset from the unrecognized file, then IE10 started rendering the styles.

Since removing the charset is not a feasible solution as this requires everybody working in my team to do this change and on that some css files with same charset get recognized.

What may be the problem ? How to resolve this ?

Comment: Just curious: What's the use case for CP437 in web development? Shouldn't switching UTF-8 be a better idea?

Comment: What is the difference between the CSS files? Why do you declare IBM437? What is their *actual* encoding? Please provide a testable case (code that lets anyone reproduce the issue).